# OnItemClickListener doesn't pop

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, onitemclicklistener

I have a list view and I am trying to catch the OnItemClickListener event.
I guess I somehow prevent it with my row properties.
Before asking this question I took a look at the forum and other questions, and tried using the solutions. It only partly helped.

Right now the I catch the event only while pressing on the side (not on any component on the layout only in the blank space, in the left side)

My listView item xml file is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="340dp"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:layout_height="160dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:background="@drawable/triangle"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"/>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/desclayout"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:background="@drawable/layout_my_posts_selector"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/myPostDescription"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:maxLength="120"
            android:hint="@string/description"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:lines="4"
            android:maxLines="5"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:textColorHint="#f7941e"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:textColor="#6d6e71"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:textSize="14sp">
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/desclayout"
        android:background="@drawable/description_layout_my_posts_selector"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_height="140dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/acceptMyPostBtn"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/my_posts_button_selector"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:src="@drawable/v"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/closeMyPostBtn"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/my_posts_button_selector"
            android:layout_below="@id/acceptMyPostBtn"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/x"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/showOnMapMyPost"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:src="@drawable/location"
            android:background="@drawable/my_posts_button_selector"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/desclayout"
        android:paddingLeft="6dp"
        android:background="#2d2d2d"
        android:layout_height="20dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:text="Finished at 19/01/2013 13:55"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And the list view definition is:

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/my_Posts_list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/my_posts_selector"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="10.0sp" />
```

I have tried adding the setFocusable:false 
to all the components and it still didn't work.

If you can guide me I will be thankful,

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
[image: List item look]

Comment: Please, post the creating class, as it could have listeners being set there. Also, as yshahak stated; `android:clickable="false"` will remove the click from that component, so if you want something to be "clik-able", then set that to `android:clickable="true"`

Answer (score 1):

Try to add:

```
android:clickable="false"
```

To every View in the List Item.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it has improved a lot, but still, if I click the text box it does not pop the event (now it pops it anywhere else) I have added a print screen of the list item if it might help

Comment: So try to remove the false clickable from it. you could also set ClickListenr to it and deliver the clickEvent to the itemClickListener with propriate values.

Answer (score 0):

Default clickable of `ImageButton` is true. So you'll need set `android:clickable="false"` to each of your `ImageButton`.